# Is C++11 lambda guaranteed to have operator()?

Tags: c++

Is this code guaranteed to work with any standard-compilant compiler ?
If it depend on C++ version, which version ?

More technically, is the Lambda guaranteed to generate a class type, and is the class generated by the Lambda guaranteed to be a class that have the unique member function `ret_type operator()(arg_types...)`, that is no possible overload ambiguity when getting `operator()` address ?

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T) {
  decltype(&T::operator()) ptr;
}

int main() {
  f([]() {});
}
```

*Why I do want to do that*: I want to get the lambda argument types, which I can only get with referencing the `operator()` because `decltype` will only work for return type.

Concretly what I try to do:

```
myVariable.f([](Name& name, Color& color) {
  // Do something with arguments
});

// myVariable is some container with multiple data
// The lambda will take only the relevant data I want to have.
// I can also write this like it, but it's just about
// 1. Experiment some template things
// 2. "Hide" heavy template notation in caller code
// 3. Save some typing

myVariable.f<Name, Color>([](auto name, auto color) {
}); // How to transform this code into the first one ?
```

Comment: Maybe there are better chances if you could say what you want to achieve and what to achieve that for. You said you want to iterate over argument types of a given lambda. If you explain what you'd need that for then maybe one can offer other solutions to your requirements.

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)?

Comment: "*I want to get the lambda argument types*" That's not going to work, since (post-C++14) the `operator()` may be a *template*. And you can't get the argument types of a template.

Comment: I saw that it's possible on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda but i don't know if it's some simplification or really like it in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can look it up in the [standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers). The chapter  **[expr.prim.lambda.closure]** describes what the generated closure type looks like. Paragraph 1 says it is a class:

> 1 The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union
> class type, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.

Paragraph 3 says that a function call operator will be present

> 3 The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator (for a non-generic lambda)
> or function call operator template (for a generic lambda) (12.6.4) whose parameters and return type are
> described by the lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively, and
> whose template-parameter-list consists of the specified template-parameter-list, if any.

The link to 12.6.4 describes that the function call operator really is `operator ()`:

> 12.6.4 Function call [over.call]
> 1 operator() shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters.

As Nicolas pointed out the question would be if you have a non-generic lambda as in your sample or a generic lambda (compare the differentiation in [expr.prim.lambda.closure] 3).

Comment: I won't have any templated lambda, the parameters will always be explicitly know (without auto), so I guess it's also possible. Thanks you.